# Add Cells of Data to a sheet based on what's selected in a specified row

Tags: javascript, validation, google-apps-script, button, google-sheets

So far The sheet can be seen in it's working form here https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HJ8PZ-zwsYDznvLleIozhg88K70ySXz0rF4fiU9uN4E/edit#gid=461565895

and an image here:
[sheet visual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GuAey.jpg)

the idea here is input button data from the second tab, then on the main generator sheet you select the buttons you want on row 4 via data validation. Next, when you press the [>] it puts all the data of the buttons you need to right of what you have so far, and you use the [v] button it puts it one row down instead.

While I got the first drop down to register and work properly, I don't understand the syntax to actually make it register all the cells in the row 4, and process them one after the other all in the same way based off of which is pressed.

(the circle to the left is going to be a function to just "clear the current string" wiping all the cells to the right of it.)

I hope that explained everything well enough, but if there is something that would make this clear, please let me know as I'm new to coding like this

```
 function addbuttontoString()
    {
      //DEFINE ALL ACTIVE SHEETS
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var eddGenSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Eddie Input Generator");
      var lrwithcontentofEddGenSheet = eddGenSheet.getLastRow()+1;
      var lcwithcontentofEddGenSheet = eddGenSheet.getLastColumn();
    
      var CharacterFrameDataSheet = ss.getSheetByName("CharacterFrameData");
      
      //Current string Variables 
      var totalcurrentstringRows = lrwithcontentofEddGenSheet-4;
      var fullcurrentString = eddGenSheet.getRange(5,1,totalcurrentstringRows, lcwithcontentofEddGenSheet);
    
      var cslastRow = fullcurrentString.getLastRow();
     var bottomrightcolumnNumber = eddGenSheet.getRange(lrwithcontentofEddGenSheet - 1, 1).getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.NEXT).getColumn();
    
    
    
    Logger.log(bottomrightcolumnNumber)
      //GET LAST ROW #OF ITEM SHEET
      var lastrowItem = CharacterFrameDataSheet.getLastRow();
      
      // Get the perfect Eddie value from Character Frame Data you are grabbing data for
      var button = eddGenSheet.getRange('B4').getValue();
      
      // Set up the Perfect Frame Variable
      for(var i = 2; i <= lastrowItem; i++)
      {
        if(button == CharacterFrameDataSheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue())
        {
          var Perfectframe = CharacterFrameDataSheet.getRange(i, 4).getValue();
        }
      }
      Logger.log(fullcurrentString.isBlank());
    
      if(fullcurrentString.isBlank()){
      // POPULATE eddGen SHEET Same Line
      eddGenSheet.getRange("A5").setValue(button);
      eddGenSheet.getRange("B5").setValue("F");
      eddGenSheet.getRange("C5" ).setValue(Perfectframe);
      } else {
      eddGenSheet.getRange(lrwithcontentofEddGenSheet-1, bottomrightcolumnNumber +1).setValue(button);
      eddGenSheet.getRange(lrwithcontentofEddGenSheet-1, bottomrightcolumnNumber +2).setValue("W");
      eddGenSheet.getRange(lrwithcontentofEddGenSheet-1, bottomrightcolumnNumber +3).setValue(Perfectframe);
      }
    }
```

Comment: ... ok? thanks for the help?

Comment: Can you show/provide example of your example input and expected output? I did not fully understood your goal when clicking  [>]  button. I'm also not sure how to configure your input generator sheet since there are a lot of data validation cells in row 4

Comment: @RonM here's a YouTube link of it working so far.: https://youtu.be/g6L__ECqQBk . I want to be able to select more than one option using those data validation cells and do the same thing I'm doing for the first cell into the cells following it.

the video is cut off, but when i press that right arrow, it adds the data to the "next cell"

Comment: Please add more details and a [minimal reproducable example] (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You can refer to this sample modification:

```
function addbuttontoString()
{
  //DEFINE ALL ACTIVE SHEETS
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var eddGenSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Eddie Input Generator");
  var lrwithcontentofEddGenSheet = eddGenSheet.getLastRow()+1;
  var lcwithcontentofEddGenSheet = eddGenSheet.getLastColumn();

  var CharacterFrameDataSheet = ss.getSheetByName("CharacterFrameData");
  
  //Current string Variables 
  var totalcurrentstringRows = lrwithcontentofEddGenSheet-4;
  var fullcurrentString = eddGenSheet.getRange(5,1,totalcurrentstringRows, lcwithcontentofEddGenSheet);

  var cslastRow = fullcurrentString.getLastRow();
 var bottomrightcolumnNumber = eddGenSheet.getRange(lrwithcontentofEddGenSheet - 1, 1).getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.NEXT).getColumn();
  Logger.log("tot: "+totalcurrentstringRows);
  Logger.log("lrwithcont: "+lrwithcontentofEddGenSheet);
  Logger.log("botRColNum: "+bottomrightcolumnNumber);

  //GET LAST ROW #OF ITEM SHEET
  var lastrowItem = CharacterFrameDataSheet.getLastRow();
  Logger.log("CharFrameLastRow: "+lastrowItem);
  
  // Get the perfect Eddie value from Character Frame Data you are grabbing data for
  var buttons = eddGenSheet.getRange('B4:J4').getValues().flat();
  

  Logger.log(fullcurrentString.isBlank());

  var dataSheetValues = CharacterFrameDataSheet.getRange(1,1,lastrowItem,4).getValues();
  Logger.log(dataSheetValues.length);
  Logger.log(dataSheetValues[0].length);

  if(fullcurrentString.isBlank()){
    var startRow = lrwithcontentofEddGenSheet;
    var startCol = 1;
    var val = "F";
  }else{
    var startRow = lrwithcontentofEddGenSheet - 1;
    var range = "A"+startRow+":"+startRow; //create A1 notation to select whole row
    Logger.log(range)
    var startCol = eddGenSheet.getRange(range).getValues().flat().filter(String).length + 1;
    var val = "W";
  }

  
  //Loop all buttons 
  buttons.forEach(button => {
    Logger.log("startColumn: "+startCol);
    Logger.log("BUTTON: "+button);
    if(button!=""){
      var perfectFrame;

      //Get the button's value in data sheet
      for(var i = 0; i<dataSheetValues.length; i++){
        if(dataSheetValues[i][0]==button){
          perfectFrame = dataSheetValues[i][3];
        }
      }

      Logger.log("frame: "+perfectFrame);
      eddGenSheet.getRange(startRow,startCol,1,3).setValues([[button,val,perfectFrame]]);
      //Increment start column
      startCol = startCol+3;
    }

  });

}
```

### Output:

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

### Changes done:

- Instead of getting the value of a single cell (B4). I get the value of the cells `B4:J4` that has data validation in your sample sheet
- Depending on if `fullCurrentString` is blank I set the startCol and startRow where the button value will be appended to its right side
- I loop all button configured, check its equivalent `perfectFrame` value and append it one at a time in the current row. After a button value was appended, I increment the startCol for the next button value to be appended.

Comment: and by the way, are the loggers in your code used to check and make sure the values are what they are supposed to be?

Comment: Yes that's correct. I used them to debug the code. You can remove them if you want

Comment: no thats a good idea. the next step is to make specific buttons only enter one cell of data but specified in the same sort of way